# Buildfire - How to make querying data more reliable

Tags: buildfire

I am making simple calls to the datastore and I am being plagued by "unhandled packets".[image: unhandled packets]

When I make calls to the datastore sometimes I'll get all my data, sometimes I'll get half, sometimes I'll get nothing like in the screenshot above. I can see the data that I'm looking for in that error message but it does not make it to my callback function.

Here is an example of a function that I run to get all of my data:

```
getData(searchObj, list) {
  let search = searchObj ? searchObj : {};
  search = { ...search, ...{ "sort": { "name": 1 }} };
  const page = search.page || 0;
  search = { ...search, ...{ pageSize: 10, page }};

  buildfire.datastore.search({}, 'some-tag', (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } 
    else {
      if (res.length === 0 || res.length !== 10) {
        const dataList = [ ...list, ...res ];
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          dataList: _.chunk(dataList, 10)
        });
      } else {
        const dataList = [ ...list, ...res ];
        search.page = search.page + 1;
        this.getData(search, dataList);
      }
    }
  })
}


getData(null, []);
```

Comment: Without seeing your code its hard to diagnose. However, sometimes the handler of an event or callback gets overridden in your code which causes a race condition to occur. This maybe why you get different results. It all depends how fast the code executes. Try putting a breakpoint inside buildfire.js to see the callback/event come through

Comment: @Daniel_Madain so if I have more than 50 records, and I want to grab the next 50, is it bad to make another request to the datastore inside of a successful callback?

Comment: @Daniel_Madain can you take a look at my edit (I added code) and see if you see anything wrong with it?